# What is the most efficient way for calculating SLA?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to figure out how can I improve my code. So basicaly there is a website and there are some events which user can do it. We are giving some summary about event result to user and SLA is one of them.

If I want to calculate event SLA, I can do it by retrieving the object and subtracting start_time from end_time.

Related Model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    ...
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

My code for calculating SLA is below.

```
events = Event.objects.all()

tmp_sla = 0
for event in events:
    time_difference = event.end_time - event.start_time
    tmp_sla += time_difference // 60 # convert seconds to minute
    
average_sla = tmp_sla // events.count()
```

The problem is there are so many events and many users. This is causing long calculating time. And sometimes I need to use more than one for loop to calculate it. Calculation time taking even longer.

Is there any built-in Django function for this? Or how can I improve my codes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to improve your code is using a custom manager. See the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/